# What is the number that shows for each user in user tab

Tags: discussion, users

In the user tab, where you can see list of all the users, there is a number displayed for each user.

What does it show?

It is not the reputation and I couldn't figure out what it is.

I'm new, sorry if it is simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the reputation they earned in the current week, as shown in the tool-tip:

[image: Reputation Tooltip: reputation this week: 1285 total reputation: 720669 (Using Jon Skeet as example user)]